# How to push just build files

Tags: git

I am trying to push a project's build files onto one of my repos but I am having trouble doing so, I need only the files inside the build folder to be in the repo, but when I do this:

```
cd build
git add .
git commit -m "Obligatory message"
git push
```

it creates a build folder on my repo with all the files in it.

This is not what I want as I want the files to be outside the build folder and on the main "dir"? of the repo if that makes any sense

I tried remaking the repo and creating the origin inside the build dir itself, however when I do this, git status shows nothing even though all the files are there. So I cant add these files to track to push them....

How can i keep track of the build files and push them WITHOUT them being in a subdirectory on the repo???

Comment: The commands you specified don't make sense. `git add .` marks files to be included the next time you run `git commit`, but you don't run `git commit`, so it's irrelevant; `git push` pushes up existing commits on the current branch. I recommend finding a git tutorial and getting to grips with the basic workflow.

Comment: Simply forgot to add that in the write up but that is not the causation of my problem

Comment: OK, but your description still suggests some fundamental misunderstandings of git, because you're talking about "adding origin in a directory" and "adding files to push them", but `git push` doesn't care about files, it just pushes whole commits. A commit, meanwhile, contains _a snapshot of the repository_, including where all the files are, so if you don't want the files to be in `build/` you need them to be somewhere else _before you commit_. You might need to step back and describe what you're actually trying to do, with some examples of what your directory structure looks like.

Comment: To add a bit to what @IMSoP said: a commit is an archive of *every* file (well, every file that is in the archive, which sounds tautological but technically isn't), plus some metadata. The push operation transfers *entire commits* (plus all their previous commits based on the metadata). To get what you want, you'd need to make special-purpose commits. To *find* those commits you'd need at least one special-purpose branch name. Then, on the other end (the Git receiving the push) you may need more special-purpose handling. Don't do this: it will cause pain and misery for a meager reward.